# WPF Expression.Samples.Interactivity dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I am trying to add namespace in xaml file as shown in link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind like below.
But I am unable to find namespace Expression.Samples.Interactivity from library even after adding reference file.
What I want to do is something like below,

```
<custom:CustomRibbonWindow x:Class="gDispatchApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:si="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=Expression.Samples.Interactivity"/>
 <!--- Above Ref is not Possible-->
 ...
 </custom:CustomRibbonWindow>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It should be `xmlns:si="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=...`. Note that you have to use `clr-namespace:` and there should not any space between the `;` and `assembly=`.

Comment: @KingKing: I apologize for my typo, I updated my question as even this is not working.

Comment: there is still a space between `;` and `assembly` in your edited code. Is that still a typo? As I said before, there should not be any space here.

Comment: @KingKing : Yes I changed that also. My worry is I am unable to get namespace using Ctrl+Space, and if I manually write, (Just like I did here), I am still not able to access any components of that dll.

Comment: you should try accessing something in that namespace in codebehind first. If it's OK, it should also be imported OK in XAML as the current code shows. Finally try compiling your code first, don't believe in what XAML editor reported to you. After compiling it should work, otherwise the actual error will be notified. If it's still notified I have no idea why here. Also be sure the reference `Expression.Samples.Interactivity` is added to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4860e371-1a26-47e0-a40a-1cd4f9cd7d2a/expressionsamplesinteractivitydll-for-wpf?forum=wpf

The one I was referring was an old article.

I probably want to take a look at

Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core(v=expression.40).aspx